# JQuery - why does appending "complex" content require an array of jquery objects over a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hard to explain so made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gsn90xqu/

Basically, if I wanted to `.append()` 2 table rows, if the content is "simple", I could append it like a string like this `.append("<tr><td>Rabit</td></tr><tr><td>Rabit</td></tr>")`. However if the content became more "complex" the only way to append it would be as an array of jQuery objects, like this `.append( [ $("<tr>..."), $("<tr>...") ] )`.

I haven't tried with other content types (e.g., `<li`); interested to learn the rule behind this. E.g., if it truly is a matter of simple vs complex content, are there character restrictions as to when something is "complex"?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know , but `test.empty().append(row_1).append(row_1)` will work. I suppose it's a jQuery bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery doesn't mention anything about requiremets for "complex" content. For that reason, I'll treat it as an assumption of yours. And what I think it's happening is that your content is malformed and jQuery is trying to do its best to interpret and sanitize the content.

You are trying to append this string content...

```
var row_1 = '<tr class="totals-row-item" data-cartid="3"><td></td><td class="name">Rabit</td><td class="notes">---</td><td class="price">$12</td><td class="deposit-price">$0</td><td class="action"><p class="zero-margin bold">Available substitutes</p><ul class="no-pad-bullets"><li>Bunny $0 rental<input type="checkbox" name="action_cart_id_"3" value="0"></li></ul><p class="bold zero-margin">Remove & refund <input type="checkbox" name="action_cart_id_"3" value="remove"></p></table></td></tr>';
```

to the following table...

```
<table id="test">
</table>
```

However, you will notice that `row_1` has malformed html because you are closing a table element (`</table>`) that was never "open"! In my opinion, that's the reason it is failing.

`append` will try to parse whatever you give it, "complex" or not, as long as the content is well-formed and the browser can handle it...

Here's an similar example with a relatively large string. The only difference is that I removed the unnecessary `</table>` tag in the `row_1` string, duplicated the same `tr` 3 times and wrapped it inside a `tbody` element. You'll see that `append` will handle that string just fine

```js
var test = $("#test")



var row_ex = '<tbody><tr class="totals-row-item" data-cartid="3"><td></td><td class="name">Rabit</td><td class="notes">---</td><td class="price">$12</td><td class="deposit-price">$0</td><td class="action"><p class="zero-margin bold">Available substitutes</p><ul class="no-pad-bullets"><li>Bunny $0 rental<input type="checkbox" name="action_cart_id_"3" value="0"></li></ul><p class="bold zero-margin">Remove & refund <input type="checkbox" name="action_cart_id_"3" value="remove"></p></td></tr><tr class="totals-row-item" data-cartid="3"><td></td><td class="name">Rabit</td><td class="notes">---</td><td class="price">$12</td><td class="deposit-price">$0</td><td class="action"><p class="zero-margin bold">Available substitutes</p><ul class="no-pad-bullets"><li>Bunny $0 rental<input type="checkbox" name="action_cart_id_"3" value="0"></li></ul><p class="bold zero-margin">Remove & refund <input type="checkbox" name="action_cart_id_"3" value="remove"></p></td></tr><tr class="totals-row-item" data-cartid="3"><td></td><td class="name">Rabit</td><td class="notes">---</td><td class="price">$12</td><td class="deposit-price">$0</td><td class="action"><p class="zero-margin bold">Available substitutes</p><ul class="no-pad-bullets"><li>Bunny $0 rental<input type="checkbox" name="action_cart_id_"3" value="0"></li></ul><p class="bold zero-margin">Remove & refund <input type="checkbox" name="action_cart_id_"3" value="remove"></p></td></tr><tr class="totals-row-item" data-cartid="3"><td></td><td class="name">Rabit</td><td class="notes">---</td><td class="price">$12</td><td class="deposit-price">$0</td><td class="action"><p class="zero-margin bold">Available substitutes</p><ul class="no-pad-bullets"><li>Bunny $0 rental<input type="checkbox" name="action_cart_id_"3" value="0"></li></ul><p class="bold zero-margin">Remove & refund <input type="checkbox" name="action_cart_id_"3" value="remove"></p></td></tr><tr class="totals-row-item" data-cartid="3"><td></td><td class="name">Rabit</td><td class="notes">---</td><td class="price">$12</td><td class="deposit-price">$0</td><td class="action"><p class="zero-margin bold">Available substitutes</p><ul class="no-pad-bullets"><li>Bunny $0 rental<input type="checkbox" name="action_cart_id_"3" value="0"></li></ul><p class="bold zero-margin">Remove & refund <input type="checkbox" name="action_cart_id_"3" value="remove"></p></td></tr></tbody>'

$("#complex_as_string").click(function() {
  test.empty().append(row_ex)
})
```

```css
.totals-row-item:first-of-type {
  background-color: gray
}

.totals-row-item:last-of-type {
  background-color: blue
}

.totals-row-item td {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="complex_as_string">
Click me to add 2 complex TRs as a string
</button>

<br><br>

<table id="test">
</table>
```

Comment: you're right the malformation fixed it! That does beg the follow-up though.... why is it that appending an array of objects worked despite the malformed `</table>` closure while appending the strings did not?

Comment: @james hard to say without inspecting `jQuery` internal processing. The only thing that's obvious is that one approach does a better job at sanitizing the content. But again, sanitation is out of the scope of `jQuery`